# Test Windows Phone App without Windows SDK

Tags: windows, testing, sdk, windows-phone

Is this possible? I have a Windows Phone because I couldn't install the Windows 8 SDK on a 32 bit OS to run an emulator. But now it seems I need the SDK too to test on actual phone too.